# Equation representing all circles in $x$-$y$ plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Find the differential equation representing all the circles in $x$-$y$ plane.

Can you please help me with this problem?

---

I have considered this $(x−a)^2+(y−b)^2=r^2$ and have got $y′′′=3y′(y′′)^2/(1+(y′)^2))$ this is because I have considered $r$ as an arbitrary constant as well along with $a$ and $b$  and so have gone with the triple differentiation of the original equation [where $y$ is considered as a function of $x$ and differentiation happens with respect to $x$], I am wondering if my answer is correct or not.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your own ideas on the problem? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to know what details are necessary in order to write a good question.

Comment: @M.Winter I have considered this $(x−a)^2+(y−b)^2=r^2$ and have got $y′′′=3y′(y′′)^2/(1+(y′)^2))$ this is because i have considered r as an arbitrary constant as well along with a and b  and so have gone with the triple differentiation of the original equation, I am wondering if my answer is correct or not.

Comment: What sets are your function $y$ defined on, i.e. what are domain and codomain?

Comment: Interesting so you have taken the two dimensional $f : \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb$ which you know is a circle and said the derivative of what equals this $f$.

Comment: @M.Winter: as the question specifies XY plane, I have assumed a 2D equation of the circle and then went forward, so I would say both domain and codomain is whole of XY plane(assumption).

Comment: @marshalcraft what do you say sir? so my answer make some sense?

Comment: @Phanindra This makes no sense. $y:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is certainly no circle. Show that you have a basic udnerstanding of differential equations to make us help you.

Comment: So you have $$\nabla ((x+a)^2+(y+b)^2)= 2(x+a)+2(y+b)$$ then the differential equation is $$\nabla f= 2(x+a)+2(y+b)$$? Or $$\nabla f -2(x+a)-2(y+b)=0$$ ? If this way right it seems sneaky. Maybe way supposed to do it is to think what "differential" terms describe circle or point traveling in circle. Like the acceleration in x direction is related to y?

Comment: We have to differentite curvature or square of it as a constant to eliminate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ as the most general form of circles with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$. Because of having three free parameters $a,b,r$ we must finally arrive at a 3-order differential equation by successive differentiation of the equation of the circles to eliminate all those constants so we start.
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$ $$2(x-a)+2y^{'}(y-b)=0$$ $$2+2(y^{'})^2+2y^{"}(y-b)=0$$
which by rearranging the terms leads to:
$$b=\frac{1+yy^{"}+(y^{'})^2}{y^{"}}=\frac{1}{y^{"}}+y+\frac{(y^{'})^2}{y^{"}}$$
by third differentiation we finally arrive at:
$$\frac{-y^{'''}}{(y^{"})^2}+3y^{'}-(\frac{y^{'}}{y^{"}})^2y^{'''}=0$$
$$\Large y^{'''}=\frac{3y^{'}}{1+(y^{'})^2}(y^{"})^2$$

Comment: For me a circle is at least a function $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$. Solutions of your equation will only give half circles. Not sure if OP meant this, though.

Comment: @M.Winter: Even I got the same answer, which is mentioned in the comments above, and wanted to know if my answer is correct or not.
Please provide me an alternate answer/solution if you consider the above answer as incomplete or wrong solution.
Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: @Mostafa: Thanks for your solution

Comment: Don't mention it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Assuming you are looking for circle equations

$$\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2,\quad t\mapsto r\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t+\theta)\\\sin(t+\theta)\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}c_x\\c_y\end{pmatrix},$$

then they are the solutions of

$$\phi''(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\phi'(t).$$

Can you see why?

Comment: but if you go by this we would end up with two arbitrary constants(if we integrate this back to get the original equation) where as the question demands 3 such variables for it to be a complete solution right?

Comment: Is it natural parameter? Shouldn't curvature be taken into account? Wouldn't ϕ′′·ϕ′=0 constitute a better form?

Comment: @Phanindra I am not sure what the "question demanded". Do you mean your comment? Above equation will give four arbitrary constants, which makes sense: one for the radius, one for the phase, two for the center position:

$$\phi(t)=r\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t+\theta)\\\sin(t+\theta)\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}c_x\\c_y\end{pmatrix}.$$

One can argue that the *phase* is unnecessary and will not change the represented circle. Currently I have no idea how to remove it.

Comment: @bipll I thought about it again. I think $\phi''\cdot\phi'=0$ only states that $|\phi'(t)|=\mathrm{const}$. This means any appropriately parametrized curve will satisfy this equation, e.g. a line $\phi(t)=p+vt$ will, because $\phi''=0$.

Comment: Yes sorry that wasn't really coherent way to solve it cause as said by others $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$

Comment: @M.Winter Sure, on a second thought this equation holds for any curve on a plane, naturally parameterized, so to narrow down the set of possible solutions we have to add a requirement that |ϕ''| is constant, this requirement formalized introduces an implicit free variable. :-\ Note that straight lines are degenerate cases of circles; if we move to complex plane, reducing infinity to a single point, and look at the inverse stereographic projection, both circles and straight lines would turn into circles on the sphere.

Comment: @bipll Only now I understand what you mean by "natural" parameter! I know this as "parametrized by arc length" :D. In this sense, *No*, my differential equation does not necessarily give a naturally parametrized curve. But it gives $|\phi'(t)|=\mathrm{const}$ because any solution to above equation must satisfy $\phi''\cdot\phi'=0$ anyway. Whether lines are okay as solution is up to OP. At least the equation in my answer does not yield lines. But this shows a loop hole. The "differential equation" $\phi'=\phi'$ is satisfied by all circles ;). Other stuff too, but does is matter?

Comment: Now I see. Yes, your equation describes any circle on Euc. plane, I was confused with those primes. I would put it like $\ddot{\varphi}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\dot{\varphi}$, to make it more mechanical.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$$

Then differentiating three times

$$x-x_c+(y-y_c)y'=0,$$

$$1+y'^2+(y-y_c)y''=0,$$

$$3y'y''+(y-y_c)y'''=0.$$

After elimination of $y-y_c$ between the last two,

$$y'''(1+y'^2)-y''^23y'y''=0.$$

---

Alternatively, express that the curvature is constant,

$$\left(\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}\right)'=0$$ or

$$y'''(1+y'^2)^{3/2}-2y'y''^2\frac32(1+y'^2)^{1/2}=0.$$

Comment: Typo, second derivative not squared

Comment: @Narasimham: yep, twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The curvature or more conveniently its square remains constant for all circles in a plane. Applying Chain Rule for curvature squared by differentiation we have

$$\Large \frac{y^{''2}}{(1+y^{'2})^3
} = \frac{2 y^{''}y^{'''}}{3(1+y^{'2})^2 2 \,y^{'} y^{''}} $$

after cancelling common factors and simplifying on either side, one is left with
$$\Large y^{'''}=\frac{3y^{'}y^{''2}}{1+y^{'2}}$$

It is much less cumbersome to start midway with the known curvature formula rather than start differentiation with a circle containg three arbitrary constants $ (h,k,R)$ and eliminate them. It also tallies with Phanindra's first comment.

Comment: Truly elegant solution, provided the radius of curvature is known.

Comment: For tag differerential equations/ differential geometry,  radius of curvature formula is well known. And its specific constant value need not be known as it disppears on differentiation.

Comment: yup, totally agreed.